# SPF = Hotmail : Pass / Gmail : Fail

Tags: dkim, spf

I have a problem with my hmailserver and DNS configuration. I've done some research like always but couldn't find a solution.

My problem is, I'm sending mail from the same configuration with the same content. I'm just testing my SMTP with some random content.

Here are my headers

Hotmail (GOING TO SPAM) :

```
x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kRyU+pBy2R9QCP2v0IhDR+nDcjJhExUZYgyI5gvwWZJm3B9+zhp1b8g9rWgPTcyugiNy5RNAKdzcQ85c68teICR4NR4jawKrGyam4AxeWgzfI4kCCw0YhWHc=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 213.xxx.77.226) smtp.mailfrom=newsletter@bulten.mywebpage.com; dkim=pass header.d=bulten.mywebpage.com; x-hmca=pass header.id=newsletter@bulten.mywebpage.com
X-SID-PRA: newsletter@bulten.mywebpage.com
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD02
X-Message-Info: M98loaK0Lo27IVRxloyPISH/oVyrdG4nMrQ10tOoOAh+4yXzzinDYnrCEwQMhKw5Kbg20/W+pSaAgRNb6qx3ZAIS4jQ8o1SuT0gLmEqUYP5WkN/qCGlIwYTMVcAEJWElUKKFHOe6+xDjYXG7bZTx832DICnQ8i2eplRpU0YjHv0=
Received: from bulten.mywebpage.com ([213.xxx.77.226]) by BAY0-MC2-F20.Bay0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
     Sun, 12 May 2013 06:11:06 -0700
dkim-signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; d=bulten.mywebpage.com; s=1368316485.mywebpage;
    c=relaxed/relaxed; q=dns/txt; h=From:Reply-To:Subject:Date:Message-ID:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding;
    bh=jFvLWT7EYZtAdGQ7lvPhguutUpw=;
    b=ntkQpaORlFsM79gFqd8WLhfuGb+nKHWSc3Iuonq6CM7A+W1xO32p+6pOxnpgMqK6/GkVnNFbBrU44NAw5hpffvon/VKcRj1S4hBl9BrfryKKAMdjHw6UvH6MwT5KE/zTzzdm66EpLzfoK6ytwPar67KArvsE1JbcUgYm/RglRGU=
Received: from bulten.mywebpage.com ([213.xxx.77.226])
    by bulten.mywebpage.com
    ; Sun, 12 May 2013 16:11:02 +0300
mywebpage
```

Gmail (GOING TO SPAM)

```
Delivered-To: webmaster@mywebpage.com Received: by 10.76.101.68 with SMTP id fe4csp131929oab;
        Sun, 12 May 2013 06:12:01 -0700 (PDT) X-Received: by 10.14.221.67 with SMTP id q43mr20043754eep.1.1368364321268;
        Sun, 12 May 2013 06:12:01 -0700 (PDT) Return-Path: <newsletter@bulten.mywebpage.com> Received: from bulten.mywebpage.com ([213.xxx.77.226])
        by mx.google.com with SMTP id z48si11728661een.205.2013.05.12.06.12.00
        for <webmaster@mywebpage.com>;
        Sun, 12 May 2013 06:12:01 -0700 (PDT) Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of newsletter@bulten.mywebpage.com does not designate 213.xxx.77.226 as permitted sender) client-ip=213.xxx.77.226; Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=hardfail (google.com: domain of newsletter@bulten.mywebpage.com does not designate 213.xxx.77.226 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=newsletter@bulten.mywebpage.com;
       dkim=neutral (no signature) header.i=@bulten.mywebpage.com dkim-signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; d=bulten.mywebpage.com; s=1368316485.mywebpage;  c=relaxed/relaxed; q=dns/txt; h=From:Reply-To:Subject:Date:Message-ID:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding;   bh=jFvLWT7EYZtAdGQ7lvPhguutUpw=;    b=NaPGwJqhXuvi4oXzwD5Ldr3I1ZqIhF8V6Q/SB7n5lbdklqNdW1IUXAJ5m0ndjOAz2xaBMhfte2PvL3aQdVRQDuLY2YDXBReznz20UCkAA6xUj0Lyvb0wrjhZgeOBIuOWrU0l+siM12fLVDAulPOKZ5s1R0RKAbJ+Leq3Lb8W76o= Received: from bulten.mywebpage.com ([213.xxx.77.226])   by bulten.mywebpage.com     ; Sun, 12 May 2013 16:11:57 +0300
```

Can anyone help me in anyway? I'm about to lose it. It's my first SMTP server configuration and I know I'm missing something.

Comment: try http://serverfault.com as this is a server related issue.

Comment: thanks! couldn't find relevant information over there though..

Comment: Regardless your question belongs there as it is server related and on top of that you have way more chances of getting an answer/assistance there. A small search gave me enough data to get started http://serverfault.com/search?q=spam+gmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the key:

```
Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of newsletter@bulten.mywebpage.com does not designate 213.xxx.77.226 as permitted sender)
```

There should be text record in the DNS of bulten.mywebpage.com in spf format that points to the mail server sending out the mail, something like this:

```
v=spf1 mx mx:mailserverdomain.com
```